# Stack audio frames for classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, speech-recognition, mfcc

I have audio files for which I extracted the mfcc features, and I ended up with train dataset of size 3082092 frames by 30 mfcc: `torch.Size([3082092, 31])`.
What is the best way to stack 10 frames to feed to the DNN?
Currently, I'm doing it this way, but I'm not sure if this is correct.
`train_data = torch.split(train_data, 10)`

Comment: do you mean how to split the dataset into batches? You can use a torch [DataLoader and Dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)

Comment: @BenedictWilkinsAI Thanks for the reply, but batch size is something else. In the context of speech recognition, the DNN cannot learn from a single audio frame. The network needs to look at several frames every time to be able to learn.

Comment: ok, use [torch.unfold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html)